# Unhandled 'error' event how to find out which line of code it's happening?

Tags: node.js

I'm getting this error:

```
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:330:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:165:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

I know it's a socket.on('error') not handled, but the problem is I don't know where this socket is in my code. It doesn't say the line. Also this error only happens every 10min or so so I can't just comment things in and out and retry. Where can I know the exact line this socket is at?

Comment: Are you using `express` or another http frameworks?  Try use a higher node version.

Comment: @hoangdv no, I'm using `http` `tls` and node 9. I'll try with a higher version.